# Problem in syncing contacts after factory reset

Tags: contacts, sync

I have reset my phone using factory reset option. Now I get "Sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly." error when trying to sync contacts. What is wrong with it? I also tried "Contacts Sync Fix" app without success.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I usually do when I experience this kind of problem is I uncheck the one having problems syncing (Contacts, Calendar, etc.) and then check it again. This should initiate a new sync and possibly fix the problem.

If it doesn't fix it, try clearing the data for Contacts app (Settings>Applications>Manage applications) and then sync again.

If it's still not fixed try removing the account that experiences this problem and then re-add it.

It also can be on Google's end, so sometimes it can fix itself, just wait a few days.

And if nothing of that helps, try by another factory reset. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the Account Permissions for the device from your Google dashboard - https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I could fix this using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.ivary.ContactsSyncFix&hl=en, though the solution basically boiled down to removing groups from my contacts. Probably I also could have created them on my Gmail account instead